# CollecitonViewCell Dynamic With based on Autolayout label Text

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I Have a Horizontal Collection View with Cells containing a label that has auto layout that expands on the size of the cell view.

Im using Xcode 8 and Swift 3.

How can I make so that my cell size is dynamic based on the text? I mean, I want it to expand, so that Otro Text... Reads complete instead of how its shown right now with the dots.

As You can see on the screenshot, now my large text gets trimmed (The Collection view, is on the area that has the Texts: Todo, Otro Text... Test1).

[image]

Hope someone can help or orient me on finding a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the you add `leading` and `trailing` constraint to the label and do not add any `width` constraint.
Next step is to give an `estimatedSize` in you `collectionViewLayout`. 
Example

```
if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(
                width: 100, height: collectionView.bounds.size.height)
        }
```

Comment: Im having a little issue .I need to fix height and not with, an I Did this:
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(
                width: 100, height: 40)
            return flowLayout.estimatedItemSize
        }
        return CGSize(width: 100, height: 40)
        
    }
And Width works ok but height is not fixed.

Comment: Had 2 do 2 comments: Width is dynamically As I expect, but height is being dynamic And I want it fixed at 40, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `estimatedItemSize` in your `UICollectionViewLayout` to be able to enable self-sizing cells. It is not possible from Storyboards, only available through code.

Comment: Thanks, can you be more specific? I get the concept you are telling me, im not sure on execution!